# Move an object along a plane in Three.js

Tags: javascript, html, three.js, orbit

So basically what I want to do is when I have a selected object I want to be able to move it around on a plane that is facing the camera. I have OrbitControls.js in the scene so I have to disable that. Here is an example of what I want: 
http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_interactive_draggablecubes.html
As you can see I want to be able to move the objects around when selected but still be able to use OrbitControls when they are not selected. Here is the code I have so far:

```js
$(function() {
  var saveCoords = {
    x: 50,
    y: 40,
    z: 0
  }

  var selectedWood;
  var hasSelected = false;
  var GUIOpen = false;
  var GUI2Open = false;
  var objects = [];
  var NoLength = document.getElementById('NoLength');
  var NoPrice = document.getElementById('NoPrice');
  var NoType = document.getElementById('NoType');

  var addGUI = document.getElementById('AddGUI');
  var addbutton = document.getElementById('add-button');
  var xButton = document.getElementById('xButton');
  var moveGUI = document.getElementById('MovementGUI')
  var xMoveButton = document.getElementById('xMoveButton');
  var addConfirm = document.getElementById('addConfirm');
  var movebutton = document.getElementById('move-button');
  var rotRight = document.getElementById('ArrowRight');
  var rotDown = document.getElementById('ArrowDown');
  var moveDist = document.getElementById('moveDist');
  var es = document.getElementById('es');

  var mDown = document.getElementById('MoveDown');
  var mUp = document.getElementById('MoveUp');
  var mFront = document.getElementById('MoveForward');
  var mBack = document.getElementById('MoveBack');
  var mRight = document.getElementById('MoveRight');
  var mLeft = document.getElementById('MoveLeft');

  var cameraDistance = 60;

  var rotation = 0;

  var scene = new THREE.Scene();
  var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, .1, 500);
  var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();

  renderer.setClearColor(0xdddddd);
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
  renderer.shadowMapSoft = true;

  //var axis = new THREE.AxisHelper(10);
  //scene.add(axis);

  var color = new THREE.Color("rgb(255,50,50)");
  var color2 = new THREE.Color(0x999999);
  var grid = new THREE.GridHelper(50, 50, color, color2);

  scene.add(grid);

  controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, scene.domElement);
  controls.enableDamping = true;
  controls.dampingFactor = 0.25;
  controls.enableZoom = true;


  var spotLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff);
  spotLight.position.set(15, 30, 15);

  scene.add(spotLight);

  camera.position.x = 50;
  camera.position.y = 40;
  camera.position.z = 0;

  camera.lookAt(scene.position);

  var loader = new THREE.FontLoader();

  loader.load("fonts/FrontPageNeue.json", function(font) {

    var textGeo = new THREE.TextGeometry("Front", {

      font: font,

      size: 5,
      height: 0,
      curveSegments: 0,

      bevelThickness: 0,
      bevelSize: 0,
      bevelEnabled: false

    });

    var textMat = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
      color: 0x666666
    });

    var textFront = new THREE.Mesh(textGeo, textMat);

    textFront.rotation.x = -1.57;
    textFront.rotation.z = 1.57;
    textFront.position.x = 50;
    textFront.position.z = 6.2;
    textFront.position.y = 0.05

    scene.add(textFront);

    var textGeo2 = new THREE.TextGeometry("Back", {

      font: font,

      size: 5,
      height: 0.02,
      curveSegments: 0,

      bevelThickness: 0,
      bevelSize: 0,
      bevelEnabled: false

    });

    var textGeo3 = new THREE.TextGeometry("Right", {

      font: font,

      size: 5,
      height: 0,
      curveSegments: 0,

      bevelThickness: 0,
      bevelSize: 0,
      bevelEnabled: false

    });

    var textGeo4 = new THREE.TextGeometry("Left", {

      font: font,

      size: 5,
      height: 0,
      curveSegments: 0,

      bevelThickness: 0,
      bevelSize: 0,
      bevelEnabled: false

    });

    var textBack = new THREE.Mesh(textGeo2, textMat);
    var textRight = new THREE.Mesh(textGeo3, textMat);
    var textLeft = new THREE.Mesh(textGeo4, textMat);

    scene.add(textBack);

    textBack.rotation.x = 4.71;
    textBack.rotation.z = 4.71;
    textBack.position.x = -50;
    textBack.position.z = -6.2;
    textBack.position.y = 0.07

    scene.add(textRight);

    textRight.rotation.x = 4.71;
    textRight.rotation.z = 3.14;
    textRight.position.x = 6.2;
    textRight.position.z = -50;
    textRight.position.y = 0.07

    scene.add(textLeft);
    textLeft.rotation.x = 1.57;
    textLeft.rotation.z = 3.14;
    textLeft.rotation.y = 3.14;
    textLeft.position.x = -4.5;
    textLeft.position.z = 50;
    textLeft.position.y = 0.07

  });




  render();

  function render() {
    controls.update();
    if (GUIOpen == true) {
      controls.enabled = false;
    } else {
      controls.enabled = true;
    }
    if (selectedWood != null) {
      hasSelected = true;
    } else {
      hasSelected = false;
    }

    if (hasSelected == true) {
      movebutton.style.visibility = 'visible';
    } else {
      movebutton.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }

    if (GUI2Open == true && moveDist.value != 1) {
      show(es);
    } else {
      hide(es);
    }

    renderer.render(scene, camera);
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
  }

  document.getElementById('world').addEventListener('mousedown', onDocumentMouseDown);

  mUp.onclick = function() {
    selectedWood.position.y += Math.round(moveDist.value * 1000) / 1000;
  }
  mDown.onclick = function() {
    selectedWood.position.y -= Math.round(moveDist.value * 1000) / 1000;
  }

  function onDocumentMouseDown(event) {
    if (GUIOpen == false) {
      event.preventDefault();
      var mouse3D = new THREE.Vector3((event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1, -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1, 0.5);
      var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
      raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse3D, camera);
      var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(objects);
      if (intersects.length > 0) {
        intersects[0].object.material.color.setHex(0xd9b38c);
        //intersects[ 0 ].object.material.wireframe = true;
        selectedWood = intersects[0].object;
      } else {
        selectedWood.material.color.setHex(13012051);
        //selectedWood.material.wireframe = false;
        selectedWood = null;
      }
    }
  }

  $(window).resize(function() {
    w = window.innerWidth;
    h = window.innerHeight;
    camera.aspect = w / h;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    renderer.setSize(w, h);
  });

  $("#world").append(renderer.domElement);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);

  addbutton.onclick = function() {
    if (GUIOpen == false) {
      GUIOpen = true;
      AddGUI.style.visibility = 'visible';
      saveCoords = {
        x: camera.position.x,
        y: camera.position.y,
        z: camera.position.z
      }
    }
  };
  xButton.onclick = function() {
    AddGUI.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    GUIOpen = false;
    hide(NoLength);
    hide(NoType);
    hide(NoPrice);
    cube.position.x = saveCoords.x;
    cube.position.y = saveCoords.y;
    cube.position.z = saveCoords.z;
  };
  xMoveButton.onclick = function() {
    hide(document.getElementById('MovementGUI'));
    camera.position.x = saveCoords.x;
    camera.position.y = saveCoords.y;
    camera.position.z = saveCoords.z;
    GUIOpen = false;
    GUI2Open = false;
  }

  moveDist.onkeypress = function() {
    if (moveDist.value > 1 && moveDist.value != 0) {
      hide(es);
    } else {
      show(es);
    }
  }

  addConfirm.onclick = function() {
    var length = document.getElementById('wood-length').value;
    var type = document.getElementById('wood-type').value;
    var price = document.getElementById('wood-price').value;

    hide(NoLength);
    hide(NoType);
    hide(NoPrice);


    if (price == "") {
      show(NoPrice);
      return;
    }
    if (length == "") {
      show(NoLength);
      return;
    }
    if (type == "type1") {
      show(NoType);
      return;
    }
    if (price != "" && type != "type1" && length != "") {
      hide(AddGUI);
      addBoard(price, type, length)
      GUIOpen = false;
      GUI2Open = false;
    }
  }

  function addBoard(e, e2, e3) {

    var dimDepth = .75;
    var dimHeight = 0;

    if (e2 == "woodType21") {
      dimHeight = 1.5;
    }
    if (e2 == "woodType31") {
      dimHeight = 2;
    }
    if (e2 == "woodType41") {
      dimHeight = 2.5;
    }

    var cubeGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(dimDepth, dimHeight, e3);
    var cubeMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
      color: 0xd9b38c
    });
    var cube = new THREE.Mesh(cubeGeometry, cubeMaterial);

    cube.position.x = 0;
    cube.position.y = 5
    cube.position.z = 0
    cube.castShadow = true;
    scene.add(cube);
    objects.push(cube);
    selectedWood = cube;
  };

  movebutton.onclick = function() {
    saveCoords = {
      x: camera.position.x,
      y: camera.position.y,
      z: camera.position.z
    }
    camera.position.y = 100;
    camera.position.x = 20;
    camera.position.z = 0;
    document.getElementById('moveDist').value = 2;
    document.getElementById('MovementGUI').style.visibility = 'visible';
    GUIOpen = true;
    GUI2Open = true;
  };

  function hide(e) {
    e.style.visibility = "hidden";
  }

  function show(e) {
    e.style.visibility = "visible";
  }

  rotRight.onclick = function() {

  }

  addBoard(2, "woodType21", 2)

  mLeft.onclick = function() {
    selectedWood.position.z = parseInt(selectedWood.position.z + parseInt(moveDist.value));
  };

  mRight.onclick = function() {
    selectedWood.position.z = parseInt(selectedWood.position.z - parseInt(moveDist.value));
  };

  mFront.onclick = function() {
    selectedWood.position.x = parseInt(selectedWood.position.x - parseInt(moveDist.value));
  };

  mBack.onclick = function() {
    selectedWood.position.x = parseInt(selectedWood.position.x + parseInt(moveDist.value));
  };

});
```

edit: bump?

Comment: Reading the code in webgl_interactive_draggablecubes will probably answer any question you have about this problem. That demo is a tiny bit more than you're asking, but the gist of it...

On mouseDown, if you've hit/picked a selectedWood, then set controls.enabled=false and make/setup a THREE.Plane (PlaneA) using the camera worldDirection and the position of the selectedWood (THREE.Plane.setFromNormalAndCoplanarPoint()).

On mouseMove, if selectedWood, raycast to PlaneA, and move selectedWood to the intersection point.

On mouse up, unset/clear selectedWood and set controls.enabled=true.

Comment: @msun I understand but idk how I would code the plane to face the camera, and be big as big as the screen. I also don't know how to find the intersect point of the raycaster on the plane...

Comment: A plane in mathematical terms is infinite... there is no "big as the screen". Btw don't confuse THREE.Plane with THREE.PlaneGeometry (which is just a finite rectangle geometry aligned to a plane.) So basically in the demo there is a line: plane.setFromNormalAndCoplanarPoint(camera.getWorldDirection(), INTERSECTED.position )... That's the gist of setting up the plane... the plane is moved to the INTERSECTED.position and aligned to camera.getWorldDirection()

Comment: Btw in that demo, the plane is setup on mouseMove. In your case, if I understand correctly, you could just setup the plane in onDocumentMouseDown using camera.getWorldDirection() and selectedWood.position.

Comment: @msun so basically my selection code using a ray caster only gets all intersected objects. How do I get the intersection point?

Comment: First you use the raycaster to get selectedWood on mouseDown (intersectObjects). Then you would use the selectedWood.position and camera.getWorldDirection() to make/setup PlaneA (setFromNormalAndCoplanarPoint). Then on mouseMove, you use the raycaster.ray.intersectPlane(PlaneA) to find the intersection point on PlaneA, and move selectedWood to that same position.

Comment: @msun when I do camera.getWorldDirection() in the set coplanar point it says invalid or unexpected token.

Comment: @msun now I get this error:
**three.js:13402 THREE.Object3D.add: object not an instance of THREE.Object3D.**
When I use the code:
**plane.setFromNormalAndCoplanarPoint(camera.getWorldDirection( plane.normal ), selectedWood.position );**

Comment: It seems you're trying to add a THREE.Plane to a THREE.Object3D. THREE.Plane is just a mathematical representation (similar to Vector3 in a sense) and can't be added to a scene. Note there are 2 main ways to go about raycasting/intersections: A) using objects/meshes and methods such as raycaster.intersectObjects() or B) using the raycaster.ray and various calculations, such as raycaster.ray.intersectPlane(). In your case, you'd use raycaster.intersectObjects() to intersect the meshes, but you'd use raycaster.ray.intersectPlane() to find the intersection point with the Plane you've created.